# Understanding the "Ecological Fallacy" in Statistics/Logic

Tags: logic

From what I understand, an ecological fallacy is the failure in reason when you make an inference about an individual based upon aggregate data of the group from which the individual belongs.

Assuming the definition above...

Suppose I am an all powerful God and know that in the set of all automobile drivers in the world, there exists a subset that break the speed limit every day and 99% of those speedsters are male.

Now, let's say I conduct the experiment of randomly choosing one person out of the set of all speedsters.  Can I infer that the person will "PROBABLY" be male?  I am being told I can't because this is an ecological fallacy.   I am inferring something about the individual from the group data, but I'm having a hard time understanding why this is a failure in reasoning.

I did not infer that they "Will BE" male.  I simply inferred that they will "PROBABLY" be male.  There is a difference.

I think it would be a safe bet to conclude that the speedsters chosen were probably male.  This seems obvious to me based up on the following simple fact... If I were to repeatedly conduct the experiment of selecting speedsters... in the long run 99% of the time those selected would be men.  Seems like a good bet to take in Vegas.

1. Am I committing an ecological fallacy here?  Why are why not?
2. If I am, where is the failure in reason?
3. Is my definition for Ecological Fallacy at the top correct?  If not, can you give me clear and concise definition or exact requirements that would allow me to classify any inference made as an "ecological fallacy"?

Comment: See related [Fallacy of division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_division): "A fallacy of division occurs when one reasons logically that something true for the whole must also be true of all or some of its parts.".

Comment: If we know that 99% of drivers are males, then picking randomly a driver we can safely conclude that "**Probably** he is a male", but (this is the fallacy) we cannot safely conclude that "He **is** a male."

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your reasoning in this instance.  I do not see this as an example of an ecological fallacy.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - Thank you!  For clarification... I'm not sure what you mean by "safely".  For example, If I were in Vegas, I think it's fair to say that I could "safely" bet on male because I would be right 99% of the time.  If I happen to be very unlucky and get it wrong then all I would need to do is anti up again.  In the long run I would get incredibly rich doing this.

Comment: @Lulu - I am making an inference about an individual based upon group data.  By definition, isn't this an ecological fallacy?

Comment: Not if your inference is a correct interpretation of the data.  If you choose uniformly at random from a group of $99$ blue balls and $1$ red one, then, by definition, there is a $99\%$ chance that you will choose a blue one.

Comment: Ecological fallacies are a poorly defined class, but they tend to involve a misattribution of broad statistical measures.  [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) is ecological, for instance, because it misattributes properties of the average.  Other variants misattribute properties of correlation (people make this type of error all the time).

Comment: Correlation fallacy:  If I produce a study which shows that shops with the best security systems suffer the greatest financial losses from theft, someone might conclude that good security systems expose you to risk, while in fact it's more likely that all this shows is that high risk shops invest in good security systems.

Comment: Or my personal favorite:  many studies show a strong correlation between violent assault and ice cream consumption, so if we want to reduce violent crime we should ban ice cream. (while in fact, both are highly correlated to the temperature so banning ice cream would, if anything, just make people angrier).

Comment: If I modify my experiment from "randomly choosing one person out of the set of all speedsters" to "randomly pulling over one person that is speeding as I drive around town" then I could be introducing an extra factor that has significant impact on the probability that the person would be male.  The extra factor could be that I am driving in an area that a lot of females.  In this case, is it fair to say that I could possibility be making an ecological fallacy stating that a person pulled over in this group would probably be male. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, your method of choosing the "random person" must be examined carefully.  For instance:  I've seen people claim that low voter turnout is irrelevant because the missing voters would just vote the same way those who showed up vote, but this is a fallacy because it assumes that "not showing up to vote" is uncorrelated to voting pattern which is a highly dubious assumption.

Comment: I think I got it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predictive reasoning you are describing is not fallacious, and is not the kind of reasoning that the [ecological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy) is concerned with.  As a general principle, if you have data that show some statistical relationship between the characteristics of people, it is legitimate to use one characteristic as a predictor of the other.  Hence, it is *massively* overbroad to say that you cannot legitimately make inferences about individuals from knowledge of group characteristics.

What the ecological fallacy is concerned with is cases where statistical associations of aggregates of characteristics over groups differ from the underlying statistical associations of the corresponding individual characteristics (e.g., cases like [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)).  The example often cited to illustrate this is in the original work of [Robinson (1950)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c823/091900242254d956f57382c157bfb7f3eaba.pdf), where the author presents an example using data on literacy and immigrant percentages in the United States.  Analysing the data over nine census regions, he observed that regions with higher percentages of immigrants tended to have higher literacy rates.  The "ecological fallacy" in this case would occur if you allowed this statistical result to lead you to (wrongly) conclude that immigrants have higher literacy rates than non-immigrants.  In fact, Robinson observed that data at the individual level confirm that immigrants have lower levels of literacy than non-immigrants.  The reason for this apparent incongruity is that immigrants tend to settle in places that have high literacy rates among the non-immigrants.

Robinson explains the relationship between correlations of characteristics in aggregates and correlations of those same characteristics in individuals depends largely on *within-group* variation.  His explanation is as follows:

> The relation between ecological and individual correlations ...
>   provides a definite answer as to whether ecological correlations
>   [i.e., correlations of characteristics in aggregates] can validly be
>   used as substitutes for individual correlations.  They cannot.  While
>   it is theoretically possible for the two to be equal, the conditions
>   under which this can happen are far removed from those ordinarily
>   encountered in data.  From a practical standpoint, therefore, the
>   only reasonable assumption is that an ecological correlation is almost
>   certainly not equal to its corresponding individual correlation. 
>   (p. 352)

---

Robinson, W. S. (1950) [Ecological Correlations and the Behavior of Individuals](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c823/091900242254d956f57382c157bfb7f3eaba.pdf). *American Sociological Review* **15(3)**, pp. 351–357.